# QGLFramebufferObject renders on screen instead offscreen

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, fbo

Im trying to render offscreen using `QGLFramebufferObject` but instead of that it renders directly on my scene.

There it is my render to FBO method

```
void GLWidget::paintToFBO()
{
    makeCurrent();
    saveGLState();

    glViewport(0, 0, figureFBO->size().width(), figureFBO->size().height());
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    figureFBO->bind();
    {
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        qglClearColor(Qt::yellow);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        qglColor(Qt::blue);
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices.constData()); 
        //Draw 4 vertices
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
    }
    figureFBO->release();
    restoreGLState();
}
```

Where is the error?

Comment: You could check for error right after `figureFBO->bind()`, or eventually the rest of the GL calls. Read more about how here: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Error

Comment: Thanks, there was an error code GL_INVALID_VALUE​, 0x0501 after bind, then i looked for other errors and find that when i initialized frame buffer object i didnt switch to current context with `QGLWidget::makeCurrent()` (i have 2 instances of QGLWidget at the same time in my app)